# How does HttpComponents send a response?

Tags: java, http, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to learn how to use Apache HttpComponents to send an `HttpResponse`. I found [some examples](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html) on the Apache site but they are very confusing and unclear.

In the code below, I cannot see where the `HttpResponse` is generated and sent back to the client. After following along in the code, it seems that it must be happening in the `HttpFileHandler` class's `handle()` method, but it's not clear where. The class just ends with

```
...
response.setEntity(body);
System.out.println("File " + file.getPath() + " not found");
...
```

without actually sending the response. It ends with setting the `Entity`.

Where does the sending of the response back to the client actually happen in this code?

```
/*
 * ====================================================================
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 * ====================================================================
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many
 * individuals on behalf of the Apache Software Foundation.  For more
 * information on the Apache Software Foundation, please see
 * <http://www.apache.org/>.
 *
 */

package org.apache.http.examples;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InterruptedIOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponseInterceptor;
import org.apache.http.HttpServerConnection;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.MethodNotSupportedException;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentProducer;
import org.apache.http.entity.EntityTemplate;
import org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpResponseFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpServerConnection;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.SyncBasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestHandler;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestHandlerRegistry;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseConnControl;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseContent;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseDate;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseServer;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

/**
 * Basic, yet fully functional and spec compliant, HTTP/1.1 file server.
 * <p>
 * Please note the purpose of this application is demonstrate the usage of
 * HttpCore APIs. It is NOT intended to demonstrate the most efficient way of
 * building an HTTP file server.
 * 
 * 
 */
public class ElementalHttpServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        args = new String[] { "e:/tutoring/236369/Tutorials/httpCoreExamples/" };
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.err.println("Please specify document root directory");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Thread t = new RequestListenerThread(8080, args[0]);
        t.setDaemon(false);
        t.start();
    }

    static class HttpFileHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {

        private final String docRoot;

        public HttpFileHandler(final String docRoot) {
            super();
            this.docRoot = docRoot;
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(final HttpRequest request,
                final HttpResponse response, final HttpContext context)
                throws HttpException, IOException {

            String method = request.getRequestLine().getMethod()
                    .toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
            if (!method.equals("GET") && !method.equals("HEAD")
                    && !method.equals("POST")) {
                throw new MethodNotSupportedException(method
                        + " method not supported");
            }
            String target = request.getRequestLine().getUri();

            if (request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) {
                HttpEntity entity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request)
                        .getEntity();
                byte[] entityContent = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
                System.out.println("Incoming entity content (bytes): "
                        + entityContent.length);
            }

            final File file = new File(this.docRoot, URLDecoder.decode(target));
            if (!file.exists()) {

                response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND);
                EntityTemplate body = new EntityTemplate(new ContentProducer() {

                    @Override
                    public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream)
                            throws IOException {
                        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                                outstream, "UTF-8");
                        writer.write("<html><body><h1>");
                        writer.write("File ");
                        writer.write(file.getPath());
                        writer.write(" not found");
                        writer.write("</h1></body></html>");
                        writer.flush();
                    }

                });
                body.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
                response.setEntity(body);
                System.out.println("File " + file.getPath() + " not found");

            } else if (!file.canRead() || file.isDirectory()) {

                response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN);
                EntityTemplate body = new EntityTemplate(new ContentProducer() {

                    @Override
                    public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream)
                            throws IOException {
                        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                                outstream, "UTF-8");
                        writer.write("<html><body><h1>");
                        writer.write("Access denied");
                        writer.write("</h1></body></html>");
                        writer.flush();
                    }

                });
                body.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
                response.setEntity(body);
                System.out.println("Cannot read file " + file.getPath());

            } else {

                response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
                FileEntity body = new FileEntity(file, "text/html");
                response.setEntity(body);
                System.out.println("Serving file " + file.getPath());

            }
        }

    }

    static class RequestListenerThread extends Thread {

        private final ServerSocket serversocket;
        private final HttpParams params;
        private final HttpService httpService;

        public RequestListenerThread(int port, final String docroot)
                throws IOException {
            this.serversocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            this.params = new SyncBasicHttpParams();
            this.params
                    .setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 5000)
                    .setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE,
                            8 * 1024)
                    .setBooleanParameter(
                            CoreConnectionPNames.STALE_CONNECTION_CHECK, false)
                    .setBooleanParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                    .setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.ORIGIN_SERVER,
                            "HttpComponents/1.1");

            // Set up the HTTP protocol processor
            HttpProcessor httpproc = new ImmutableHttpProcessor(
                    new HttpResponseInterceptor[] { new ResponseDate(),
                            new ResponseServer(), new ResponseContent(),
                            new ResponseConnControl() });

            // Set up request handlers
            HttpRequestHandlerRegistry reqistry = new HttpRequestHandlerRegistry();
            reqistry.register("*", new HttpFileHandler(docroot));

            // Set up the HTTP service
            this.httpService = new HttpService(httpproc,
                    new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy(),
                    new DefaultHttpResponseFactory(), reqistry, this.params);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Listening on port "
                    + this.serversocket.getLocalPort());
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                try {
                    // Set up HTTP connection
                    Socket socket = this.serversocket.accept();
                    DefaultHttpServerConnection conn = new DefaultHttpServerConnection();
                    System.out.println("Incoming connection from "
                            + socket.getInetAddress());
                    conn.bind(socket, this.params);

                    // Start worker thread
                    Thread t = new WorkerThread(this.httpService, conn);
                    t.setDaemon(true);
                    t.start();
                } catch (InterruptedIOException ex) {
                    break;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err
                            .println("I/O error initialising connection thread: "
                                    + e.getMessage());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class WorkerThread extends Thread {

        private final HttpService httpservice;
        private final HttpServerConnection conn;

        public WorkerThread(final HttpService httpservice,
                final HttpServerConnection conn) {
            super();
            this.httpservice = httpservice;
            this.conn = conn;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("New connection thread");
            HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext(null);
            try {
                while (!Thread.interrupted() && this.conn.isOpen()) {
                    this.httpservice.handleRequest(this.conn, context);
                }
            } catch (ConnectionClosedException ex) {
                System.err.println("Client closed connection");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (HttpException ex) {
                System.err.println("Unrecoverable HTTP protocol violation: "
                        + ex.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    this.conn.shutdown();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running a server here.

The generic code to "talk HTTP" is already implemented by the library.

You just have to plug in the "business logic" (in the form of an HTTPRequestHandler).

Your "business logic" gets an instance of HTTPResponse as a parameter. This object has already been created for you by the library. You can set parameters and write data to.

When your handler method returns (or even before that as you manipulate the response object), the library takes care of getting the data over the network.

> Where does the sending of the response back to the client actually happen in this code?

As the result of method `handle` the response object now contains an Entity with your inner class that can write out a file. That code will be called to send the data.

It might be instructive (or possibly overwhelming) to put a breakpoint in your code and step through (including the part after handle returns) to see the control flow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So the `handle` method is simply for placing the custom headers and entities etc. while the actual sending is being done by some other method in some other class as a result of calling `handleRequest()` on `httpService`?